# Text-align: right; keep a margin no matter what I try

Tags: javascript, css

I've got this simple code that displays the Day of the week, the time and the date. The text should be aligned on right, as specified in the css, but I don't know why it doesn't fix itself on the right side of the screen (excluding the margin) it always keep a big space between the side of the window and itself.

https://jsfiddle.net/czh9cam6/

```
 <div class="droite" id="time" >
 </div>

#time{
    text-align: right;
    display:table-cell;
}

.droite{
    width: 73%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Try using your browsers developer tools. There is a margin on `#aszone` and the body itself.

Comment: @KilianStinson I do indeed have a margin of 20px on each side of the ASzone, but as you probably noticed, the margin on the right is way higher than 20px. That's the point I don't understand

Comment: It's not the margin, it's the width of the table. You can set the width of `aszone` to `calc(100% - 40px)` (40px goes for twice your margin) and it would work. You can also remove `display: table` as suggested below.

Comment: Excelent Oboer ! Thank you very much. So if I understand correctly, when i'm working with margin, I should substract them from the 100% width ? I though the width was automaticaly calculated using the marges

Comment: Margin is area outside of the box and as far as I'm aware it's not included in width (contrary to padding and border).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `display: table;` in `#aszone` and add `float: left` and `float: right` to `.gauche` and `.droite` respectively.

https://jsfiddle.net/qsdtfztf/

Comment: Thank you Roger, this is what I was looking for.. tho the text is no longer vertically aligned in my div, how can I fix that ?

Comment: If you know the exact height, you can set the `line-height` of the text element to be the same height as the container's. http://jsfiddle.net/qj40hfvd/

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add `display:table-cell` property in your code.
Just Remove that property... Then It will margin as per your requirement.
Checkout Your Answer :

```js
(function () {
    function checkTime(i) {
        return (i < 10) ? "0" + i : i;
    }

    function startTime() {
      var months = [ 'Janvier', 'Fevrier', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juillet', 'Aout', 'Septembre', 'Octobre', 'Novembre', 'Décembre' ],
          days = [ 'Dimanche', 'Lundi', 'Mardi', 'Mercredi', 'Jeudi', 'Vendredi', 'Samedi' ]
    
        var today = new Date(),
            d = today.getDay(),
            f = today.getDate(),
            m = today.getMonth(),
            y = today.getFullYear(),
            
            h = checkTime(today.getHours()),
            i = checkTime(today.getMinutes());
        
        var val = days[d]+'<br>'+h+':'+i+"</span><br>"+f+' '+months[m]+' '+y;
        
        document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = val;
        
        t = setTimeout(function () {
            startTime()
        }, 500);
    }
    
    startTime();
})();
```

```css
#time{
 text-align: right;
 //display:table-cell;
  
}

#aszone{
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 height: 10%;
 display:table;
 background-size: cover;
}

.gauche{
 width: 27%;
 text-align: left;
 display:table-cell;
}

.droite{
 width: 73%;
 //display:table-cell;
 vertical-align:middle;
    margin-left:20px;
}

.helper{
 display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

img{

 vertical-align: middle;
 width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div id="aszone">
            <div class="gauche">
              <span class="helper"></span>
              <img src="http://www.tablesandfables.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/youtube-logo.jpg">
            </div>

            <div class="droite" id="time" >
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Many browers have default style，just like there is always 8px margin around the body element in chrome. So what you should do is clearing default style.

Answer (score 0):

Such as:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```